# Python: prevent signals to propagate to child threads

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

```
import threading
import time

def worker(i):

    while True:
        try:
            print i
            time.sleep(10)
            break
        except Exception, msg:
            print msg



threads = []
for i in range(10):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t1)

for t in threads:
    t.start()


print "started all threads... waiting to be finished"
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

if i press ^C while the threads are running, does the thread gets the SIGINT?
if this is true, what can i do from the caller thread to stop it from propagating SIGINT to running threads?

signal handler in caller thread would prevent it?
or do i need signal handler for each thread?

Answer (score 2):

> if i press ^C while the threads are running, does the thread gets the SIGINT?

No. As it says in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads):

> Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread of the main interpreter, even if the signal was received in another thread.

You can see that this is true with a simple test:

```
import threading
import time

def worker():
    while True:
        print('Worker working')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pass


worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
worker_thread.start()

while True:
    print('Parent parenting')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

After you send SIGINT with ^C, you will see that the main thread is killed (no more 'Parent parenting' logs) and the child thread continues to run.

In your example, your child threads exit because you `break` out of their `while` loops after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As referred in [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), you should use the attribute **daemon**:

> daemon: A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon
>   thread (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is
>   called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is
>   inherited from the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon
>   thread and therefore all threads created in the main thread default to
>   daemon = False.
>
> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are
>   left.
>
> New in version 2.6.

To control the CTRL+C signal, you should capture it changing the handler with the **signal.signal(signal_number, handler)** function. The child process inherits the signal handler for SIGINT.

```
import threading
import time
import signal


def worker(i):
    while True:
        try:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(10)
            break
        except Exception as msg:
            print(msg)


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    print("I will wait for all threads... waiting to be finished")
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

threads = []
for i in range(10):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t1)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

print("started all threads... waiting to be finished")
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: i want to explictly join them.

Comment: if the child thread inherits the signal handler, will each thread try to join on threads (the list)? for t in thread: t.join() is that block called once or by all threads?